# How to add swipe up and down to UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5

I've added in my `ViewController`:

```swift
let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGestureToScroll))
swipeUp.direction = .up
swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
        
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGestureToScroll))
swipeDown.direction = .down
swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

But when the gesture is inside my `UITableView` ( that's subview of my view ) my method `handleGestureToScroll` aren't called. Otherwise when I remove my tableView it's working.

How can I add this gesture to work in my `UITableView`?

Comment: How can a table view both scroll up and down normally and respond to an up or down swipe gesture recognizer? Those actions seems indistinguishable and doomed to conflict one way or the other.

Comment: @matt but is possible for example add two touch gesture for the same element, why not can added two 'observables' to swipe? My methods isn't to scroll the table, is to make some actions if it's happen.

Comment: I'm just saying you need to mediate between them somehow as they are naturally in conflict. And it is actually _not_ always possible to "add two touch gesture for the same element"; if you add two single-tap UITapGestureRecognizers on the same view, what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding those gestures to all your cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGestureToScroll))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGestureToScroll))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    return cell
}
@objc func handleGestureToScroll() {
    print("swipe is handled")
}
```

Comment: Only way to add swipe gestures to tableView is adding on the header/cells?

Comment: Well, this is what I found so far. Maybe there could be much better solution @ThiagoValente.